# Google Analytics throws NoClassDefFoundError at runtime

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, android-studio-2.1

When compiling project, it works fine but when run it throws a runtime exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fiz.AnalyticsTrackers$1
```

Everything is well configured like added google analytics dependency in gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
}
```

Permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Initialization and trigger event from code base

```
AnalyticsTrackers analyticsTrackers = AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance();
Tracker tracker = analyticsTrackers.getTracker();
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category).setAction(action).setLabel(label).build());
```

Here AnalyticsTrackers is a custom class which contains common GoogleAnalytics functionality.

Comment: Please Update your Library first 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'

Comment: Updated to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0' but same error throws.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fiz.AnalyticsTrackers$1

Comment: what is this package ,,,, com.fiz.AnalyticsTrackers$

Comment: It is a custom Analytics Tracker class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112897/discussion-between-droidarc-and-aditay-kaushal).

Comment: Are you using ProGuard?

Comment: Yes. But it is disabled. Here is the snippet  of build.gradle
            "minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'"

Comment: Have you used Multidex enable feature?

Comment: No. Is there any necessity to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Multidex support solve this problem. Here is how to configure it.

In build gradle file

```
 defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
 }

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

In my application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```